# torque in zero gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, torque

Possibly that's a duplicate.

Say we have two drums $A$ and $B$ in a zero gravity with moments of inertia $J_a$ and $J_b$ respectively, placed on a same axis, running through their centers of mass. Drum $A$ contains a motor, which applies torque $T$ to drum $B$. How $\dot \omega_a$ and $\dot \omega_b$ are related to $T$? I understand that

$J_a \omega_a + J_b \omega_b=0$ (conservation of angular momentum)

and

$J_a \dot \omega_a + J_b \dot \omega_b = 0 $ (Newton's second and third laws).

but what about $J_a \dot \omega_a - J_b \dot \omega_b$ ? Does it equal to $T$ or $2T$ or what? How $T$ is distributed over these two drums?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I got it. Full system is

$$
\begin{cases}
J_1 \dot \omega_1 + J_2 \dot \omega_2 = 0 \\
J_1 \dot \omega_1 - J_2 \dot \omega_2 = T,
\end{cases}
$$

so
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot \omega_1 = \frac{T}{2 J_1} \\
\dot \omega_2 = {- \frac{T}{2 J_2} }
\end{cases}
$$