# torque and infinite moment of inertia

Tags: angular-momentum, inertia

As a continuation of the previous question here:
[torque in zero gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/306806/torque-in-zero-gravity)

Say we have two coaxial drums with known moments of inertia $J_1$ and $J_2$. If the first drum contains a motor, which acts on the second drum with torque $T$ then angular accelerations are

$$
\cases{
\ddot \theta_1 = -\frac{T}{2 J_1} \\
\ddot \theta_2 = \frac{T}{2 J_2}
}
$$.
Then if $J_1 \to \infty $ then $\ddot \theta_1 \to 0$ and still only half of $T$ is used to accelerate the second drum. This is counter-intuitive to me. I thought that if drum 1 is fixed in some inertial system, then all the $T$ will be spended to accelerate the second drum.

So where am I wrong? What I am missing?
May be it is a definition of T that is bad?

UPD:

The correct equations are : 
$$
\cases{
\ddot \theta_1 = -\frac{T}{ J_1} \\
\ddot \theta_2 = \frac{T}{ J_2}
}
$$.

Comment: The angular accelerations are $$ \cases{
\ddot \theta_1 = -\frac{T}{ J_1} \\
\ddot \theta_2 = \frac{T}{ J_2}
} $$

Comment: I've added a minus to second equation, but are you sure that there is no 2?

Comment: Yep. Both drums experience equal and opposite torque. Not half the torque each. Also I added the minus to the one with the motor because it a reaction torque from the torque applied to the second.

Comment: Ok, fixed it again. And what if the motor is fixed? only $T$ will be applied to second drum?

Comment: I suggest that you revise your question, in view of the comments by ja72.

Comment: I meant to suggest that you reconsider asking whether the result is counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The motor generates torque $T$ that is applied to the second body to accelerate it. The acceleration is $$ \ddot{\theta}_2 = \frac{T}{J_2}$$

A reaction torque is passed through the housing of the motor to the first body causing the acceleration $$\ddot{\theta}_1 = - \frac{T}{J_1}$$

If $J_1 \rightarrow \infty $ then logically $\ddot{\theta}_1 = 0$

The *relative* acceleration is $$\ddot{q} = \ddot{\theta}_2 - \ddot{\theta}_1 = \frac{T}{J_1} + \frac{T}{J_2} = \frac{T}{J^\star}$$

<sub>where $J^\star = \left( \frac{1}{J_1} + \frac{1}{J_2} \right)^{-1}$ is the reduced combined MMOI of the system</sub>

In view of these facts I hope you recognize that the statements in *OP* are incorrect.

Comment: you possibly mean $\ddot \theta_1$, not $\theta_1$ ?

Comment: @sammygerbil, yes I forgot to invert once. I edited the answer.